# Equality in the A.M G.M inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, lagrange-multiplier, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a_1, a_2,\cdots a_n$ be positive real numbers. The A.M-G.M inequality states that
$$(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)^\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_n}{n}$$ with equality if and only if $a_1=a_2=a_3\cdots =a_n$.

I was able to prove the inequality using Lagrange Multipliers method. Can anyone help me prove the Equality part. i.e if A.M=G.M then $a_1=a_2=a_3\cdots =a_n$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A proof for AM-GM inequality (Apostol: Mathematical Analysis)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1713971/a-proof-for-am-gm-inequality-apostol-mathematical-analysis)

Comment: If they are equal then you have $\left(a_1^n\right)^{\frac1{n}}$ on the LHS and $\frac{n\cdot a_1}{n}$ on the RHS.

Comment: @callculus42 he is saying that the AM=GM not the inverse.

Comment: @Youem Oh yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you have proved LHS $\le$ RHS by some way.

Now we prove that if LHS $=$ RHS, then $a_1 = a_2 = \cdots = a_n$.

Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that LHS = RHS for
some positive real numbers $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n$,
not all equal.

WLOG, assume that $a_1 < a_2$.
Let $b_1 = b_2 = (a_1 + a_2)/2$.
We have $b_1 + b_2 = a_1 + a_2$ and
$$b_1b_2 - a_1a_2 = (a_1 - a_2)^2/4 > 0.$$
If we replace $a_1, a_2$ with $b_1, b_2$, we get
LHS $>$ RHS. A contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if you were able to do it by Lagrange Multipliers then AM$=$GM implies $\left(a_1,\ldots,a_n\right)$ satisfies the KKT. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Can you please what you mean by KKT?

Comment: How did you manage to prove the inequality by Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: ooOOOooo I need to go backwards and use that if the equality holds then the extremum is achieved

Comment: Yes! That's all.